# Prepaying tax vs. estimated tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, estimated

Does the US government really care whether tax payments during the year are filed as quarterly Estimated Income Tax versus a single prepayment before year's end of >90% of the previous year's tax calculation?

For me, one payment would be a lot simpler.

Heck, I might even be willing to pay it all on the first quarter just to avoid having to file three more times...

Comment: My _state_ explicitly suggests paying the whole year estimated at the first quarter date. Of course state liability is normally much smaller than federal.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it does. See [form 2210 and its instructions](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-2210).

Specifically [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i2210#en_US_2021_publink1000305515):

> **The penalty is figured separately for each installment due date**. Therefore, you may owe the penalty for an earlier due date even if you paid enough tax later to make up the underpayment. This is true even if you’re due a refund when you file your tax return. However, you may be able to reduce or eliminate the penalty by using the annualized income installment method. For details, see [Schedule AI Annualized Income Installment Method](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i2210#en_US_2021_publink1000305556), later.

Comment: Well, grump. Thanks for the pointer. "The object of the game is to be as honest as the law allows..."

Comment: @keshlam one thing to point out is that the form 2210 allows you to ask the IRS to figure out the penalty instead of calculating it yourself. They might decide that it's not worth wasting their time (but that's a gamble). If they do calculate it - you'll have to pay.

Comment: Actually, the instructions for form 2210 seem to say that those of us who retired in 2020 or 2021 at age 62 or above may be able to request an exemption from the penalties. I don't know whether that's a COVID-19 courtesy or if it's a recognition that most retirees are still trying to figure out their revised finances for the first few years. I need to take a closer look at that.

Comment: @keshlam: if you just retired _and_ have reasonable cause. That provision has been there (with the actual years shifting of course) back to 2006, the oldest I have stored on my external drive -- and in 1995 which I found on the [IRS prior-years search](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs-prior-search).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if you need to make estimated tax payments, a sufficient amount of estimated taxes need to be paid by each quarter, or you will have an underpayment penalty for that quarter. What is a sufficient amount is calculated as the minimum of two methods (1/4 of the safe harbor amount for the whole year, or the amount from the Annualized Income installment method, whichever is less). Even if you make up the underpayment in earlier quarters with bigger payments in later quarters, you cannot avoid the penalty for the earlier quarter (however, you stop the penalty from growing, since the penalty is the interest of the underpayment between when it was due and when it was paid).

On the other hand, you *can* make up an underpayment in earlier quarters by increasing withholding in later quarters. This is because, by default, withholding is treated as divided evenly among the quarters, no matter the actual distribution of your payments through the year (unless you elect to count withholding based on the date they were actually paid). So if you noticed an underpayment in earlier quarters, and you have enough paychecks left in the rest of the year to contribute enough withholding to reach the safe harbor by the end of the year with withholding alone, you can do that, and you will avoid underpayment penalties for all the quarters. (Note that changes to W4 might take some paychecks to take effect, depending on the company.)

Comment: Now if only I had something to withhold from. Ah well. The penalty isn't awful, just annoying and my own fault.

Comment: @keshlam: If you convert Traditional IRA to Roth, you might be able to withhold from that.

Comment: Always burn down the non-tax-advsntaged savings first. I've got several years before I start tapping actual retirement accounts.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You need to pay the taxes as you accrue them.  That is the whole point of quarterly payments.  It's only "quarterly" as a compromise between the government's cash flow needs and the paperwork burden.

If paying once a year would suffice, they would simply make it April 15.

> For me, one payment would be a lot simpler, and may let me dodge pulling money out of slumping investments when I'm feeling optimistic about their recovering later in the year.

For *employees*, as you know, withholding is an "escrow" system - let's not mince words, it's to keep the money from being squandered. Taxpayers are fallible, and so are their transmissions, stuff happens. The estimated tax payments are exactly the same system - it is your IRS escrow account into which you must pay expected taxes. On such a short 90-day window, professional and prudent investment advice would **not** be to put it into risk investments.  As a self-earner you are deemed responsible enough to be trusted with money for 90 days - you don't need biweekly payments like wage earners.

Thus in principle, the tax money should always be available in quasi-cash, *because you just earned it in the last 90 days*.  Quarterly payments are not a surprise.

I don't know how you got into a situation where you *didn't* self-escrow the tax portion of your income, but that was a mistake and don't do it anymore lol.  Just sock it into a savings account and pay it to the IRS every 90 days. Be doing dry runs on your taxes (I have a spreadsheet) and as you get closer to end of year, make adjustments e.g. if you have been overpaying.

It sounds like what you're really trying to do is game your IRS escrow account in securities. I would say borrow that same amount of money, then. As to whether it's sensible to borrow it *from the IRS*, you'll have to examine the interest and penalty schedule vs. any commercial offerings available to you.  But you should have done that math at the outset.

Comment: How I got into the situation: Retirement, so no withholding from paycheck. Only income Is what I have to report from capital gains, interest, and a small safety-net annuity, plus a few bucks of hobby and interest on an in-family mortgage. Not trying to game it so much as trying to minimize the paperwork.

Comment: Oh, so a traditional IRA or 401K type deal.  Yeah, you need to take the tax money out when you take the spending money out.  Can't do one without the other.  I'm feverishly converting all my traditionals to Roth, after witnessing everyone in my parents' assisted living facility forced to surge withdrawals from their traditionals to meet big medical/care expenses... and they end up in insane tax brackets. The promise of "lower tax brackets in your retirement years" was unrealistic.

Comment: Still spending down the non-401k, so for now I still have to mangle it myself.

Comment: It's almost worth the penalty to not have to worry about the deadlines.

Comment: @keshlam Yeah, I agree with your last.

Comment: The point about tax brackets in retirement is very interesting

Comment: Tax brackets is a massive It Depends.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS cares that they get each quarter's estimated payment on or before the due date that for that quarter. Since the due date for the first quarter is before the due date for the other three quarters, you can pay your entire estimated tax then, at the opportunity cost of not having it for the rest of the year.

See [Form 2210](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2210.pdf), Part 3, lines 12 and 18. If you overpay in one quarter, that's on line 18 for that quarter. It gets carried in to line 12 of the next quarter, where it gets treated as though same as a payment made in the next quarter.

Answer (score 0):

For the last 7 yrs, i started making a single tax payment estimated according to calculated taxs for previous year.

About a yr or 2 ago, IRS started a new computing system for businesses to report employee taxes and salaries online, quarterly, and instantly process tax amount. Previously businesses had until june 30th to report info which is well after April.
This last year, irs caught up with me. I received a notice for each year regarding over and under payments. Letters either said to contact them to schedule payment plan or to contact them to give my bank deposit info.
The final 7th letter listed all my over and underpayments calculated with penalties for the years of underpayment and enclosed a check of $2538, which was remaining amount owed to me.

BTW - i set my monthly tax payment super low to barely cover taxes, i have cashed out a 18yr 401k at 43 yrs old to invest in a business that in the end broke even. My  penalty charges were only for making 3 annual tax underpayments.

Oh, i also work state and city jobs, meaning i don't pay into social security.

The way i see it, irs is screwing themselves with audits. There are probably more people who over pay than people who under pay.

Comment: That is why they don't audit everyone. They do an initial scan looking for suspicious patterns and take a closer look at those, and they watch for numbers reported from multiple sources not lining up, and they do a statistical sampling to keep everyone honest. And in fact the auditors are perfectly happy if they find an error whose correction reduces our tax, just as they're perfectly happy to see us take legitimate tax breaks. They want every dollar they're owed, no more and no less. "The object of the game is to be as honest as the law allows", for all players.